# Deeplearning4j difficulty using LibSVM files with CNNs

Tags: java, deep-learning, sparse-matrix, libsvm, deeplearning4j

I am using the LibSVM record reader to load sparse data into neural networks.

This worked fine when using a MLP model, but when I tried to load data into one of the example CNNs given in one of the problems:

```
ComputationGraphConfiguration config = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
            .trainingWorkspaceMode(WorkspaceMode.SINGLE).inferenceWorkspaceMode(WorkspaceMode.SINGLE)
            //.trainingWorkspaceMode(WorkspaceMode.SEPARATE).inferenceWorkspaceMode(WorkspaceMode.SEPARATE)
            .weightInit(WeightInit.RELU)
            .activation(Activation.LEAKYRELU)
            .updater(Updater.ADAM)
            .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same)
            .regularization(true).l2(0.0001)
            .learningRate(0.01)
            .graphBuilder()
            .addInputs("input")
            .addLayer("cnn3", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder()
                .kernelSize(3, vectorSize)
                .stride(1, vectorSize)
                .nIn(1)
                .nOut(cnnLayerFeatureMaps)
                .build(), "input")
            .addLayer("cnn4", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder()
                .kernelSize(4, vectorSize)
                .stride(1, vectorSize)
                .nIn(1)
                .nOut(cnnLayerFeatureMaps)
                .build(), "input")
            .addLayer("cnn5", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder()
                    .kernelSize(5, vectorSize)
                    .stride(1, vectorSize)
                    .nIn(1)
                    .nOut(cnnLayerFeatureMaps)
                    .build(), "input")
            .addVertex("merger", new MergeVertex(), "cnn3", "cnn4", "cnn5")
            .addLayer("globalPool", new GlobalPoolingLayer.Builder()
                    .poolingType(globalPoolingType)
                    .dropOut(0.5)
                    .build(), "merger")
            .addLayer("out", new OutputLayer.Builder()
                    .lossFunction(LossFunctions.LossFunction.MCXENT)
                    .activation(Activation.SOFTMAX)
                    .nIn(3*cnnLayerFeatureMaps)
                    .nOut(classes.length)
                    .build(), "globalPool")
            .setOutputs("out")
            .setInputTypes(InputType.convolutionalFlat(32,45623,1))
            .build();
```

I got an error that seems to be saying that it was getting 2-dimensional data, but it needs 3-dimensional data (with the third dimension being a trivial one).

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid input: expect output columns must be equal to rows 32 x columns 45623 x channels 1 but was instead [32, 45623]
```

How do I give it the 1 channel dimension?

Failing that, how do I get the CNN to recognize channel-less data, or how do I give a CNN sparse data?

Thank you

Comment: I think I just realized this is stupid... Why would I use a CNN like this...

Comment: Feel free to ask your question on the DL4J support channel: gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Answer (score 1):

The typical problem you run in to when setting up cnns is setting the input type wrong. Deeplearning4j's equivalent of an "input layer" is an input type where we configure common configurations like rnns or cnn flat depending on the type of data you are dealing with. Typically if you are using cnns, you would want to look at the InputType.convolutionalFlat 
method.

That will take a flat vector and convert it to a proper 1 channel tensor meant for use with cnns. If you use input type, it will also automatically set things like the number of inputs and outputs for you.